# Does anyone have code for routines to create the namespace in Dynamic CRM, to set a field visible in a form?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Hi I am about to set off on the journey to write a code to hide the other field in Dynamic CRM until the option is selected by the user. Do you know of an out of the box way to do so? From my research I gather that there is no way thus before I begin my javascript-ing, does anyone have code that will hide the other field in forms until the option is clicked by the user?

Comment: If it is an option then deploy 2013 and use business rules - quicker and simpler than javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "setVisible" and "addOnChange" are going to be your travel buddies.

Answer (score 0):

Journey complete ;)

If anyone needs:

```
function showOtherOption(otherfield, optionset) 
{
    var xp = Xrm.Page;
    var option = xp.getAttribute(optionset);
    var other  = xp.getControl(otherfield);

    option && 
    other  && 
    other.setVisible( option.getText().toLowerCase() == "other" );
}
```